# IE null when click back button

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, internet-explorer, html, coffeescript

I really ran out of resources now.  It seems like a browser level issue. Everyone seems to talking about sloppy code on javascript side, not sure if it's applicable at all. I have a Rails 3.1.1 app with lots of javascript (jQuery/coffeescript) on a single main page (the page is based on html5boilerplate).  Anytime, I try to click refresh or when I click away from the site and click back.  It simply gives me a "null" at the top left corner of the page.  Nothing shows in Rails' log/console as if the page wasn't hit at all.  Any inspiration/direction is much appreciated.

Comment: Not much I can do without some example code. Doesn't look like it has anything to do with rails to me (Ruby doesn't use the word "null", JS does). But really, you need to post some code. Narrow it down to what you think might be the offending code (not the entire document) and someone will take a look.

Comment: I don't know what the offending code maybe(the entire file seems too much to be posted). I put the entire application.js generated by rails into jslint and it spited out lots of warning (nothing seems could be causing that much trouble, mostly are indentation, number of spaces from "(" or errors of that nature which is rendered by coffeescript engine and shouldn't really be an error.  I think my next possible move would probably be remove blocks of code individually and narrow it down by putting them back in blocks at a time.  Really didn't want to go to that direction but I guess I have to.

Comment: cleaned up all the jslint warning and I am still getting the same type of error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks bricker.  And whoever for giving me a negative.  I should have tested this a little more before I post the question. After cleaning all the javascript warnings via jslint and removing all javascript completely from the page.  I realized it's a controller mistake.  Basically, I have a respond_to block responding with .js as following and that gave me an error because IE for some reason looked for the .js instead of the .html